# Pass Interface to another service in Startup.cs ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to pass an Interface as a parameter in another service's constructor.

MSAuthService constructor needs 3 parameters:

```
public MSAuthService(string jwtSecret, int jwtLifespan, IUserService userService)
{
    this._jwtSecret = jwtSecret;
    this._jwtLifespan = jwtLifespan;
    this._userService = userService;
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserManager>();
....
services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(
    new MSAuthService(
        MyConfigurationManager.GetJWTSecretKey(),
        MyConfigurationManager.GetJWTLifespan(),
        // I want to pass IUserService as parameter here
        )
);
```

I couldn't figure out how to pass the IUserService to MSAuthService's constructor. I don't want to pass UserManager (concrete) class as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddSingleton` has an overload that accepts a `Func<IServiceProvider, TImplementation>`.

You can use the `IServiceProvider` to retrieve the registered dependency, using `GetRequiredService`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(sp =>
    new MSAuthService(
        MyConfigurationManager.GetJWTSecretKey(),
        MyConfigurationManager.GetJWTLifespan(),
        sp.GetRequiredService<IUserService>()
        )
);
```

Comment: I tried your answer. I got this error: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'ABC.Business.Abstract.IUserService' from root provider.'

Comment: And you have registered an implementation for `IUserService`?

Comment: Yes. I have UserManager.cs class.

Comment: @emert117 scoped service cant be injected into singleton in that way. You'll need to change the lifetime scope of the one of the services

Comment: I changed `services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>...` to `services.AddScoped<IAuthService>` . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

‍did you try to use this on `Configure` method?

```
var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUserService>();
```

Comment: Mmm, Nice solution my old friend 

Comment: @AmerllicA...  :)